# Styling radio buttons and only show selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

'm currently working on a project, there are two options and I am wanting to have a pointing finger image rather than the standard radio button, as well as this I was wondering if it would be possible to only show the radio image for the one that is selected only.

I have tried using a js library but can't seem to get it to work

Current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.screwdefaultbuttonsV2.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input:radio').screwDefaultButtons({ 
    image: "url(images/hand.png)",
    width:   39,
    height:  17
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

        <div id="content">


<label for="LiquoriceandPeppermint" class="check">Liquorice and Peppermint<input type="radio" name="flavour" id="LiquoriceandPeppermint" value="option1" /></label><br>

<label for="RooibusCremeCaramel " class="check">Rooibus Crème Caramel <input type="radio" name="flavour" id="RooibusCremeCaramel " value="option2" /></label>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons are rendered by the OS, not the browser. Styling them has always been limited and non standardized across browsers. You're better off trying to style the label to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

try css:

```
input[type='radio']:checked {
    background: url("images/hand.png") center center no-repeat;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can create completly custom radio buttons. Even different icons...

```
 input[type="radio"] {
        display:none;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
input[type="radio"] + label {
    display:inline;
    font-size: 18px;

}
input[type="radio"] + label:before {
    content: '';
    display:inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

input[type="radio"][class="customRadio"] + label:before {
    background: url('../icons/bc.png') no-repeat;
}

input[type="radio"][class="customRadio"]:checked + label:before {
    background: url('../icons/bc1.png') no-repeat;    
}
```

Comment: Hey Jacob, thanks for the help, I have tried to implement it but the custom radio button isn't showing, I've put it on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rukWF/